# fancyhdr formatting help

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Hello guys I am fairly new to LaTeX and this website has never let me down :D I am here once again for some help since I am a total noob. I need a bit of coding help to get a specific style on my header in a project I am working on. It has elements of date, some static text like project or job ID and then page number like page 2 of 24 or something. This is what I am using so far

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.PNG}}
\rhead{\thepage}
```

[image: What I have now]

I also want the black horizontal line to disappear. oh and also there is numbering on the middle bottom section of the page as well. but I am sure I can figure how to clear that out. Anyway here is an example of what I want

[image]

sorry about my ms paint skills. I would want the block of text on the right to be right justified if possible. Thank you again

Comment: An alternative to `fancyhdr` would be `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Or `titleps` from the `titlesec` bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to centre the right-hand text w.r.t. the image on the left, with a `\parbox` rather than a`minipage`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=0.75in,head=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} % to remove the line
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{gerald-mcboing-boing}}% use your logo
\rhead{%
\parbox[b][2cm][c]{5cm}{\raggedleft
\today\\
some text\\
Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you are using the same height `2cm` for both image and `parbox`.

Comment: @Sigur: If one wants to centre image and text, isn't that the simplest thing to do?

Comment: I don't know. I think so. I just asked to understand your code. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the height of header according to your logo. After, remove the option `showframe` to hide the guidelines.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[showframe,head=2cm,top=1cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% to remove the line
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}% use your logo
\rhead{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{5cm}
\flushright
\today\\
some text\\
Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}
\end{minipage}}
\cfoot{}


\begin{document}\pagestyle{fancy} 
foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply good sir/madam but unfortunately I am getting an error with this. LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry. I commented out the geometry line I was using since it was clashing and I got this really weird page with nothing showing and several lines

Comment: Please, try to compile my whole code. What is the option with problem in `geometry`? I don't have errors here.

Comment: That is because you (or some package you load)  already load `geometry` with other options. Just replace the line: `
\usepackage[showframe,head=2cm,top=1cm,includehead]{geometry}` with `\geometry{showframe,head=2cm,top=1cm,includehead}`.

Comment: LaTeX Error: \headrule undefined. =/

Comment: \lhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo.png}}% use your logo for this it gives this error Undefined control sequence.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`. Out of interest, please add `listfiles` to the very first line of this example document, compile and copy the first five lines here.

Comment: @BakhtawarKhattak I don't know if you got a ping. ^^^^^^^

Comment: Thank you so much man I love.. I manage to fix it.. can the box on the right be moved slight up like a few mm... its not falling exactly in the middle line of the logo when I resize it to the size I want.. can you give me a command for that so I can adjust it

Comment: @BakhtawarKhattak, it is not ideal, but you can use `\\ \bigskip` to insert a vertical space on the right box.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative proposal using `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[showframe,head=70pt,top=1cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\ihead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
\ohead{%
  \begin{tabular}{r@{}}
    \today\\
    some text\\
    Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much everyone. I love this place it has always helped me. Gonna ask another question soon. I am sending you all a virtual cookie here ... "O" its a cookie with vanilla frosting xD